# Connection to Azure IoT MQTT hub via SIMCOM 5300E GPRS Module

Tags: azure, mqtt, gsm, gprs

I need to connect a custom hardware device to Azure IoT hub via MQTT. I am using a SIMCOM 5300E GPRS module controlled by a Microchip PIC24F micro controller via the UART.

For the initial prototype I was able to connect to standard MQTT brokers like Mosquito and CloudMQTT. I wrote the custom C libraries to construct the "Connect", "Subscribe" and "Publish" commands. This worked perfectly via a TCP/IP connection.

I made an Azure IoT hub and created a device. The SAS token was successfully generated using device manager. I am able to send and receive messages to MQTTbox. So I know the hub, device and SAS token are all working correctly. Because the device we are creating is intended for a volume market I am limited in hardware to a 16 bit micro controller and therefore unable use the Azure IoT SDKs. I am following the advice here "Using the MQTT Protocol Directly"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly

I'm using AT commands to open a connection to the server.

`AT+CIICR`  (connects successfully)

`AT+CIFSR` (I get a local IP)

`AT+CIPSSL=1` (Enables the SIM5300E SSL function, though I'm not sure how this works or what certificate it uses.)

`AT+CIPSTART="TCP","xxxxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net","8883"` (Where xxxxxxxxxx is my hub name. I get "Connect OK)

`AT+CIPSEND` (The server returns the ">" prompt)

At this point I sent the "Connect Packet" followed by the CTRL-Z. I get "Send OK" but there is no response and the server closes the connection. If I send something like "PING" I get no response but the server does not usually close the connection.

The code I use to generate the string is :

```
const char MQTTProtocolName[10] = "MQTT";
const char MQTTLVL = 0x04;
const char MQTTFlags = 0xC2;
const char MQTTUsername[100] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.azure- 
devices.net/LumenTest002/api-version=2016-11-14";
const char MQTTPassword[200] = "SharedAccessSignature srxxxxxMYSASxxxxx";
const char MQTTQOS = 0x00;

void connect_MQTT(void)
{
//Calculate MQTT Lengths
MQTTProtocolNameLength = strlen(MQTTProtocolName);
MQTTClientIDLength = strlen(MQTTClientID);
MQTTUsernameLength = strlen(MQTTUsername);
MQTTPasswordLength = strlen(MQTTPassword);
datalength = MQTTProtocolNameLength + 2 + 4 + MQTTClientIDLength + 2 + 
MQTTUsernameLength + 2 + MQTTPasswordLength + 2;

//Get Prompt
__delay_ms(100);
putsU2("AT+CIPSEND"); //Send the command to 5300E
__delay_ms(3000);

//Send Byte - Declare as connect
putU2(0x10); //0x10 = Fixed value determined by MQTT Standard
//Send Byte - remaining Length
putU2(datalength & 0xFF);
//Send 2 Bytes - Protocol Length
putU2(MQTTProtocolNameLength >> 8);
putU2(MQTTProtocolNameLength & 0xFF);
//Send Bytes - Protocol Name
for (Counter = 0; Counter < MQTTProtocolNameLength; Counter++)
    {
    putU2(MQTTProtocolName[Counter]);
    }
//Send Byte - Level
putU2(MQTTLVL);
//Send Byte - Flags
putU2(MQTTFlags);
//Send 2 Bytes - Keep Alive
putU2(MQTTKeepAlive >> 8);
putU2(MQTTKeepAlive & 0xFF);
//Send 2 Bytes - Client ID Length
putU2(MQTTClientIDLength >> 8);
putU2(MQTTClientIDLength & 0xFF);
//Send Bytes - (MQTTClientID);
for (Counter = 0; Counter < MQTTClientIDLength; Counter++)
    {
    putU2(MQTTClientID[Counter]);
    }
//Send 2 Bytes - MQTTUsernameLength
putU2(MQTTUsernameLength >> 8);
putU2(MQTTUsernameLength & 0xFF);
// Send Bytes -(MQTTUsername);
for (Counter = 0; Counter < MQTTUsernameLength; Counter++)
    {
    putU2(MQTTUsername[Counter]);
    }
//Send 2 Bytes - MQTTPasswordLength
putU2(MQTTPasswordLength >> 8);
putU2(MQTTPasswordLength & 0xFF);
// Send Bytes - MQTTPassword
for (Counter = 0; Counter < MQTTPasswordLength; Counter++)
    {
    putU2(MQTTPassword[Counter]);
    }
//Send Byte - CTRL-Z
putU2(0x1A); 
}
```

Using the "AT+CIPACK" I receive the response "+CIPACK 130,130,0" which indicates that 130 bytes have been received by the server but I have no response.

So I have two questions :

1. Is the connection correctly opened over SSL?
   I assume I would not get the "Connect OK" or the ">" prompt if it were not.
2. Is my MQTT "Connect" packet constructed correctly?
   It uses the same Oasis MQTT Standard V3.1.1 and works on all other brokers I have tried. i assume the "MQTTProtocolName" is simply "MQTT" as I could find no other reference to it. I  made the "Username" and "Password" as instructed in the link above. The SAS token is currently valid.

Comment: I believe you're getting "Connect OK" in response to the TCP handshake, not TLS establishing. Are you sure your SoC can do at least TLS 1.0? Also, how does it validate the *.azure-devices.net certificate? There should be a way for you to flash the public part of that cert into the modem so it can validate it, or find a way to skip validation altogether.

Comment: You did not say that you got TLS sessions working to Mosquitto or CloudMQTT. That would be my next step.

Comment: Hi,

I have confirmed the 5300E has SSL over TCP. The problem was in the construction of the hex packets which is extremely specific (also Azure is picky about what  it will accept ) but I have it working now. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @patrickm77. Can you give me a bit more details how you resolved the issue? I have a SimCom5320 modem which fails to open HTTPS session to Azure Website (using AT+CHTTPSOPSE command) but works perfectly fine if I publish the same site to the cloud service. The domain and the certificate are the same. Not sure how to debug it further.

Comment: I'd check have you sent the command to enable SSL: "AT+SSLOPT=1"